# Java - Actionlistener: Get components from parent

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, actionlistener

The only way I found so far to get other components' info when an actionevent is activated is by doing the following:

```
((Swing Component)ActionEvent.getSource()).getParent().getComponent(---).method();
```

and while it work it's not that practical or readable, not to mention would most likely stop working properly if I moved around the components in the parent component.

So what is the best way to go about this? Should I even use an actionlistener to begin with or are there better classes/design for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the listener an inner class, and access the component directly:

```
private JLabel label;
private JButton button;

MyPanel() {
    ...
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("button clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html

Inner classes were invented mainly for that specific reason.

Comment: Actually that's how I already have it, the problem is that the components are created in a parent class. I store all components at any given time in a hashmap so I guess I could just access the elements I need there and send it to the constructor inside actionPerformed.