# Get index number of a certain container in arraylist of jpanels

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel

I was wondering if there was a method for ArrayLists, similar to indexOf(), that could tell me what the element number of a particular container was.

Say I had an ArrayList that held Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> stringHolder = new ArrayList<>();
```

If I were looking for the element number of the String that contained "example", I would just call:

```
stringHolder.indexOf("example");
```

to find my answer.

How can you do this wth JPanels? Especially if all of the containers are virtually the same. I need to be able to remove a specific container from its parent panel by pressing a button within that container. The action listener would remove the container from the panel. But, I need to know the element number of that particular container. TIA.

Comment: Java.util.ArrayList class method indexOf(Object o) is used for finding out the index of a particular element in a list, It already has IndexOf() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the "index" of a component held in a container, you need to get the component array from container by calling `getComponents()`, then to find your desired component, you need to iterate through the array, testing to see if you've gotten what you want.

Note that you could use the static `Arrays.binarySearch(Object[] a, Object key)` method to achieve this, but also note that for this to work well, your JPanel should override equals and hashCode so that this method will work, so that the key will match the JPanel of interest, without having to already have the component of interest in hand.

Note that obtaining a reference to a component this way is fairly "kludgy" meaning it risks leading to brittle programs that can form bugs more easily than you want. Better to have other cleaner ways of getting your reference, such as placing your key components in an ArrayList or Map.

---

Edit: for your program, you already have a reference to the clicked JPanel. Since the JCheckBox is held by that JPanel, you can get a reference to the JCheckBox via its listener's `getSource()` method, and then get a reference to its "parent" container, the JPanel, by calling `getParent()` on the JCheckBox.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Each ArrayList element holds an entire container, not an individual component.

Comment: @JohnEakin: key components should probably be assigned to fields. Grouping containers should probably be in their own class.

Comment: @JohnEakin: Note that your JPanel reference is already easy to get. See edit.

Comment: Where in the API could I find more info on the getSource() and getParent() methods?

Comment: (1+) for perseverance.  @JohnEakin, boy this is annoying!!! I specifically suggested you should use `getSource()` and `getParent()` (hours ago) and even wrote the code for you in the question you have now deleted. Its frustrating that you don't pay attention to the answer provided and now waste the time of every other person who has read your previous two posting on the topic. By the way the simple answer to you last comment is to read the API and/or search the forum for example that use those methods.

Comment: @camickr It is not that I disregarded your previous answer. I viewed it on the mobile app, but unfortunately, it had mystically magically deleted itself when I went to refer to it on my computer. So, I am sorry that it seems as if I just ignored the effort you put in. On another note, I did end up finding the two methods in the API. (Although I could not find an in-depth page on getParent() )

Comment: Fast forward a few days, I have another problem and a question. I made an inner class to execute the code for my checkbox. When you suggested I use getSource() and getParent(), I assumed you meant something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21962156/7309137 (replace setText with getParent) Is there any way to do this with local variables instead of fields?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ^^^ I forgot to tag you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44252622/10251345), using a similar method, if you know the location of the component you want, to find the "index" of a component held in a container you could use:

```
index = Arrays.asList(container.getComponents()).indexOf(container.getComponentAt(x, y));
```